# nginx complex procedural rewrite rule -- plugin? separate server?

Tags: python, nginx

I need to use nginx to serve static files (many, many files, most small, but also a mix of big video files).  Configuring nginx as a static file server is, of course, pretty easy except...

... the processing we need to take the "input" path (where the user thinks the file is) and convert it to the real location is too complex to be expressed using nginx's rewrite engines.  In general, the logic that does the computation is currently expressed in a Python library.  (Just accept it's too complex to be an nginx rewrite rule.)

What are my options for making nginx be able to apply my custom rewrite rules to arrive at the proper path for serving the files?  I've thought of these 2 options:

1. Write some C code that I add to nginx that calls out to Python and does my computation.  (For this answer, it doesn't even matter that it's Python.

   I'm just injecting C code into nginx that will do an arbitrary computation.)  I have, though, no clue as to where to even start looking for where to make this modification to allow nginx to do this.
2. Is it possible that nginx can query a separate backend process (basically a very simple tornado server) and say "hey, given path X what path Y should I serve)?

   While not ideal to go cross process, I figure if the two processes are on the same machine, the latency should be low.
3. Just write a tornado server which does the computation and then does a redirect to nginx.

   This is do-able, but then requires our client code to handle redirects, and (a) this feels slower and (b) I don't feel like messing with the clients to make them handle redirects, since now they have to go roundtrip twice to the server.
4. ??

Comment: What do you think you will gain by considering the files as static and thus wanting them to be served by nginx. Why not just use nginx as the frontend and your application as the server, as it's a pattern that is extremely well supported. I guess I'm a little puzzled on what you are trying to achieve. Maybe I'm wrong, but I would assume that asking an application to give the path to the file and then loading the file with nginx will not be more efficient than letting the application return the file's content directly.

Comment: The documentation for tornado says rather explicitly that using it to serve large static files (bigger than fit in memory) probably won't end well.  Since serving many, many files quickly to a reasonably large set of clients demands that you not block, I would think nginx would be better suited to this task than a tornado server?   (A single client can request hundreds to thousands of images at a time, in quick succession.)

Comment: For second option there is `X-Accel-Redirect` and it works almost as you said. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-redirect

Comment: Thank you!!!  I think X-Accel-Redirect is exactly what I was looking for, and armed with that nugget, I immediately found several people who are doing pretty much exactly this. (I didn't mention it, but part of the computation of the new URI is also authentication, i.e. if the client is allowed access.)  Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The [Lua nginx module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) is probably the answer you are looking for. It can be configured to call out to an external process to decide how to handle a request, similar to what you're describing in your question, or even to figure out how to handle a request entirely on its own (possibly by querying a database).